# How can I use a Jekyll plugin from within a custom plugin?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, jekyll-extensions

I'm writing a bit of documentation for a jQuery plugin I authored and want to include functional code snippets in the docs.  I can achieve what I'm looking for by doing this:

```
{% capture snippet %}
    $('selector').use_plugin(args);
{% endcapture %}
<script>
    $('#snippetTrigger').on('click', function() { {{snippet}} });
</script>
{% highlight javascript %}{{ snippet }}{% endhighlight %}
```

This seems like a much better job for a short custom plugin with the following syntax:

```
{% code_snippet snippetTrigger %}
    $('selector').use_plugin(args);
{% endcode_snippet %}
```

which would have output identical to the previous plugin-free code.

The issue I'm having is with the `{% highlight %}` part. If I just include that in the output from my custom plugin, it just prints it as output. I want it to appropriately highlight the code via Pygments. How can I make my Jekyll plugin use the standard `{% highlight %}` plugin?